# dgrid 0.4.0 tree looks flat before user interacts

Tags: dojo, tree, dgrid, dstore

Trying to use dgrid 0.4.0 to display a tree structure. (no prior experience with previous versions 0.3.x).

I built this sample with two folders : alice and bob ; each would have a few files (leaves) in it.

The store ("astore.js")

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare',
       './dstore/Memory',
       './dstore/Tree'],

       function(declare, Memory, Tree) {
           var store = new (declare([Memory, Tree], {}))();

           store.add({node:'bob',     id:1, parent:null, hasChildren:true});
           store.add({node:'alice',   id:2, parent:null, hasChildren:true});

           store.add({node:'thesis',  id:3, parent:1,    hasChildren:false});
           store.add({node:'game',    id:4, parent:1,    hasChildren:false});
           store.add({node:'picture', id:5, parent:2,    hasChildren:false});
           store.add({node:'plan',    id:6, parent:2,    hasChildren:false});
           store.add({node:'mail',    id:7, parent:2,    hasChildren:false});

           return store;
       });
```

And the startup script :

```
require(['dojo/_base/declare',
        'app/dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
        'app/dgrid/Tree',
        'app/astore'], 
        function (declare, OnDemandGrid, Tree, astore) {

            w = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Tree],{}))({
                collection: astore,
                columns:[
                    {field:'node', label:'Whatever...', renderExpando:true}
                ]
            }, 'slot');

            w.startup();
        });
```

The data always looks flat when the widget is displayed :

[image]

After I click on "bob", that part gets sorted out :

[image]

Then I click on "alice", and all looks fine at last :

[image]

However if I sort on a column, I mess the whole stuff up again, worse than ever :

[image]

I've experimented with the sample code from the laboratory, and get the same results. My dgrid components were downloaded via Bower. This issue is present on two different computers, with different OSs and browers. And I'm running dry on ideas... :S Any input extremely appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by Dylan and myself on the [github issue](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/1097) with the same question, you need to pass a collection to your grid that only represents the top-level items.  When using `dstore/Tree`, you can call `store.getRootCollection()` for this purpose.

So instead of `collection: astore`, you want `collection: astore.getRootCollection()`.

Comment: Hello Ken. Yes sorry for the cross-posting, I've thought of the wrong place first I guess. When I passed .getRootCollection, all I got was a tree with *only* the root items. However this was with my own implementation of the tree model, before moving onto the Tree store mixin with the standard property names parent / id / hasChildren. I guess that two issues got mixed up. Thanks for the clarification !

Comment: If I had to wager a wild guess, perhaps your original implementation didn't have a common `root` referencing the original store that both `getRootCollection` and `getChildren` referenced for their work, so `getChildren` ended up attempting to grab children from the already-filtered parents-only collection.  `dstore/Tree` is basically 4 1-line method implementations, so it's easy to use as a base or reference implementation.

Comment: That's exactly it. I did't reckon the need for an actual private root element. That's the most useful information I've had today. Owing you !