# Dgrid not rendering the tree structure correctly

Tags: javascript, tree, dojo, dgrid, dstore

I'm a beginner to JavaScript, dojo dgrid, dstore and still struggle to overwrite the store's property methods correctly:

My data structure:

```
[{"id":"T1","name":"Test","desc":"Rectangular 1",qty":null,"parent":null},    
{"id":"C1","name":"Test 2","qty":0.0,"parent":"T1"},    
{"id":"S1","name":"Test 3","qty":6.0,"parent":"C1"},    
{"id":"S2","name":"Test 4","qty":6.0,"parent":"C1"},    
{"id":"S3","name":"Test 5","qty":6.0,"parent":"C1"}
]


        var StandardGrid = declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection, Selector, Editor, dgridTree]);
        var CustomStore= declare([Rest, dstoreTree]);

        var myStore = new CustomStore({
            target: "./data.json",
            idProperty: "id",
            getRootCollection: function () {
                return this.root.filter({ parent: null });                  
            },
            getChildren: function (object) {
                return object.parent = object.id;
            },
            mayHaveChildren: function (object) {
                return object.parent == null;
            },
        });

        var treeGrid = window.treeGrid = new StandardGrid({
            collection: myStore.getRootCollection(),
            columns: [
                { renderExpando: true, label: "Name", field: "name", sortable: false },
                { label: "Quantity", field: "qty" },
            ]
        }, "treeGrid");

        treeGrid.startup();
```

I also tried to refer to the below link but still can't figure out:
[dgrid 0.4.0 tree looks flat before user interacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889591/dgrid-0-4-0-tree-looks-flat-before-user-interacts)

Appreciate and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data is invalid, one qty is missing "

Comment: When you say it's "not rendering correctly", how *is* it rendering vs. how *should* it be rendering?  It certainly looks like your `getChildren` implementation is incorrect though, and if your data is coming back with all items at once, you probably don't want to be using `Rest`...

Comment: The tree should have 3-layer where root (id=T1) follows by second-layer (id=C1) and lastly third-layer (id=S1,S2,S3). Currently it list all data without a tree. I will try replace Rest with others like memory store. Could you kindly tell me also what's wrong with my getChildren implementation with my current dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally made the Dgrid Tree hierarchy working after substiture Rest store to RequestMemory store and put in additional field hasChildren into dataset to be used in mayHaveChildren method and also getChildren after adviced by Ken Franqueiro.

{"id":"C1","name":"Test 2","qty":0.0,"parent":"T1", **"hasChidlren":true**}

```
        var StandardGrid = declare([Grid, Keyboard, Selection, Selector, Editor, Tree]);
        var MemoryTreeStore = declare([RequestMemory, TreeStore]);

        var myStore = new MemoryTreeStore({
            target: "./data.json",
            idProperty: "id",
            getRootCollection: function () {
                return this.root.filter({parent: null});                    
            },
            getChildren: function (object) {
                return this.root.filter({parent: object.id});
            },
            mayHaveChildren: function (object) {
                return object.parent == null || object.hasChildren == true;
            }
        });
```

I think one have to consider how they structure their tree dataset in order to work to overwrite dstore/Tree methods.